# if I select userid I want to get particular operator in dropdown box pls correct the query

Tags: entity-framework

```
var names = (from u in _dbContext.OperatorUsersNew

  join s in _dbContext.Users on u.UserId equals s.UserId
  join r in _dbContext.Roles on u.RoleId equals r.RoleId
  where r.IsDeleted == false 
      && r.IsActive == true 
      && u.IsActive == true 
      && u.IsDeleted == false 
      && r.RoleTypeId >= roleType
      && u.UserId==(operatorID==0?u.UserId : operatorID)
  select u
);
```

Comment: Show your models ...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.